# Automotive Q&A Area

Tags: discussion, area-51

I recently got more heavily involved in StackOverflow, and I've been quite pleased with the wide variety of topics we have. I have noticed however that we are lacking a place for topics related to automotives.

As someone who is very technically minded, I often find myself looking for information regarding cars, since it's an area I have very little expertise. I think it would be terribly helpful.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See [Cars](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37674/cars), [Motor Vehicle Driving](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45256/motor-vehicle-driving) and [Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1321/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair)

Comment: Welcome to MSO! Requests for new sites aren't handled through this site. You'll probably want to check out the existing [__Cars__ proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37674/cars) at Area 51, the place where new sites are discussed/incubated.

Comment: Forums?  *Forums??*  ***FORUMS???***

Comment: @Won't I take it you prefer ["Fora" over "Forums"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4292)? Or is that not what you're so subtly hinting at? :p

Comment: @Bart Robert Cartaino's hint was more subtle. `;)`

Comment: @SamHuckaby Stack Exchange sites are not forums: They are Q&A sites. That is what Won't is trying to say. `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno I see! I'll change the topic to be appropriate ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then head over to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), take a look at the current proposals (perhaps [Cars](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37674/cars) fits the bill?).

If you find nothing - make a proposal!

Comment: Ah! I didn't even realize that was what Area 51 was for... haha. thank you!